# Using a Reactor Netty HttpClient, how can the client be configured to send more that one item using a Flux publisher to a server?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor-netty

The more specific question is why does Flux.fromIterable() not work with the Reactor Netty HttpClient?
This simple example works just fine. All 10 items are emitted by the Flux publisher:

```
public class ConcurrentLinkedQueueFluxTest {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> aList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> clq = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        aList.stream().forEach(i -> clq.add(i));

        Flux.fromIterable(clq)
                .subscribe(new ReactiveSubscriber<Integer>());
    }
}
```

Using the ReactiveSubscriber:

```
class ReactiveSubscriber<T> extends BaseSubscriber<T> {

    private Subscription subscription;

    @Override
    public void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        System.out.println("In hookOnSubscribe");
        this.subscription = s;
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void hookOnNext(T response) {
        System.out.println("In hookOnNext: "+response.toString());
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void hookOnError(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void hookOnComplete() {
        System.out.println("In hookOnComplete");
        subscription.cancel();
    }
}
```

As shown below if I use a similar Subscriber with HttpClient.send(Flux.fromIterable()) only 1 item is emitted, not all the items in the queue. So something is not configured correctly since this Flux.fromIterable() method that creates a Flux is not working with HttpClient.

For the actually production code issue, I have included the queue definition, the client method, the subscriber, the server method and a log that shows only 1 of 5 items are sent from the client to the server.
It appears that even though the HttpClient send() method has a Flux object loaded from the queue, only one item is sent, although the queue has 5 items.

The items to be sent to the server are in a Queue of type ByteBuf:

```
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ByteBuf> electionRequestQueue;

    public ElectionTransactionRequest() {
        electionRequestQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ByteBuf>();
    }
```

The client method is:

```
     public void task() {

        log.debug("Queue size: "+electionRequestQueue.size());

        ElectionTransactionSubscriber etSubscriber = new ElectionTransactionSubscriber();

        HttpClient.create()
             .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpClient.host("localhost"))
             .port(61005)
             .protocol(HttpProtocol.HTTP11)
             .post()
             .uri("/election/transaction")
             .send(Flux.fromIterable(electionRequestQueue))
             .responseContent()
             .aggregate()
             .asByteArray()
             .subscribe(etSubscriber);
     }
```

The subscriber is defined as:

```
class ElectionTransactionSubscriber extends BaseSubscriber<byte[]> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElectionTransactionSubscriber.class);

    private Subscription subscription;

    @Override
    public void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        log.debug("In hookOnSubscribe");
        this.subscription = s;
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void hookOnNext(byte[] response) {
        log.info("In hookOnNext");
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void hookOnError(Throwable t) {
        log.error(t.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void hookOnComplete() {
        log.debug("In hookOnComplete");
        subscription.cancel();
    }
}
```

The server side is defined in the method:

```
    public void start() {

        disposableServer =
            HttpServer.create()
                .host("localhost")
                .port(61005)
                .protocol(HttpProtocol.HTTP11)
                .route(routes ->
                    routes
                        .post("/election/transaction",
                            (request, response) -> response.send(request
                                                                .receive()
                                                                .aggregate()
                                                                .flatMap(aggregatedBody ->
                                                                    electionTransactionHandler.electionTransactionResponse(aggregatedBody)))))
                        .bindNow();
        disposableServer.onDispose().block();

    }
```

When the client is run, the queue has 5 items in it, but only one item is sent to the server as shown in the log. In the subscriber the method hookOnComplete() is called after only 1 item from the Flux publisher is sent.

```
2020-12-01 12:03:56,442 DEBUG [main] com.dd.vbc.business.services.client.requests.ElectionTransactionRequest: Queue size: 5

2020-12-01 12:03:56,539 DEBUG [main] com.dd.vbc.business.services.client.requests.ElectionTransactionSubscriber: In hookOnSubscribe

2020-12-01 12:03:56,746 INFO  [reactor-http-epoll-1] com.dd.vbc.business.services.client.requests.ElectionTransactionSubscriber: In hookOnNext

2020-12-01 12:03:56,746 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-1] com.dd.vbc.business.services.client.requests.ElectionTransactionSubscriber: In hookOnComplete
```

Comment: Do you have found a way?

Answer (score 0):

Buffering would probably be the easiest for you to use.    It emits buffers (which are Collection — by default, List).  So in your case the Subscriber would receive a List

```
StepVerifier.create(
    Flux.range(1, 10)
        .buffer(5, 3) //overlapping buffers
    )
        .expectNext(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
        .expectNext(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
        .expectNext(Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9, 10))
        .expectNext(Collections.singletonList(10))
        .verifyComplete();
```

=========================

This is directly from the documentation for reactor-core:

Three Sorts of Batching

When you have lots of elements and you want to separate them into batches, you have three broad solutions in Reactor: grouping, windowing, and buffering. These three are conceptually close, because they redistribute a Flux into an aggregate. Grouping and windowing create a Flux<Flux>, while buffering aggregates into a Collection.
Grouping with Flux<GroupedFlux>

Grouping is the act of splitting the source Flux into multiple batches, each of which matches a key.

The associated operator is groupBy.

Each group is represented as a GroupedFlux, which lets you retrieve the key by calling its key() method.

There is no necessary continuity in the content of the groups. Once a source element produces a new key, the group for this key is opened and elements that match the key end up in the group (several groups could be open at the same time).

This means that groups:

```
Are always disjoint (a source element belongs to one and only one group).

Can contain elements from different places in the original sequence.

Are never empty.
```

The following example groups values by whether they are even or odd:

```
StepVerifier.create(
    Flux.just(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 11, 12, 13)
        .groupBy(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd")
        .concatMap(g -> g.defaultIfEmpty(-1) //if empty groups, show them
                .map(String::valueOf) //map to string
                .startWith(g.key())) //start with the group's key
    )
    .expectNext("odd", "1", "3", "5", "11", "13")
    .expectNext("even", "2", "4", "6", "12")
    .verifyComplete();
```

Warning
Grouping is best suited for when you have a medium to low number of groups. The groups must also imperatively be consumed (such as by a flatMap) so that groupBy continues fetching data from upstream and feeding more groups. Sometimes, these two constraints multiply and lead to hangs, such as when you have a high cardinality and the concurrency of the flatMap consuming the groups is too low.
Windowing with Flux<Flux>

Windowing is the act of splitting the source Flux into windows, by criteria of size, time, boundary-defining predicates, or boundary-defining Publisher.

The associated operators are window, windowTimeout, windowUntil, windowWhile, and windowWhen.

Contrary to groupBy, which randomly overlaps according to incoming keys, windows are (most of the time) opened sequentially.

Some variants can still overlap, though. For instance, in window(int maxSize, int skip) the maxSize parameter is the number of elements after which a window closes, and the skip parameter is the number of elements in the source after which a new window is opened. So if maxSize > skip, a new window opens before the previous one closes and the two windows overlap.

The following example shows overlapping windows:

```
StepVerifier.create(
    Flux.range(1, 10)
        .window(5, 3) //overlapping windows
        .concatMap(g -> g.defaultIfEmpty(-1)) //show empty windows as -1
    )
        .expectNext(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        .expectNext(4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
        .expectNext(7, 8, 9, 10)
        .expectNext(10)
        .verifyComplete();
```

Note
With the reverse configuration (maxSize < skip), some elements from the source are dropped and are not part of any window.

In the case of predicate-based windowing through windowUntil and windowWhile, having subsequent source elements that do not match the predicate can also lead to empty windows, as demonstrated in the following example:

```
StepVerifier.create(
    Flux.just(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 11, 12, 13)
        .windowWhile(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .concatMap(g -> g.defaultIfEmpty(-1))
    )
        .expectNext(-1, -1, -1) //respectively triggered by odd 1 3 5
        .expectNext(2, 4, 6) // triggered by 11
        .expectNext(12) // triggered by 13
        // however, no empty completion window is emitted (would contain extra matching elements)
        .verifyComplete();
```

Buffering with Flux<List>

Buffering is similar to windowing, with the following twist: Instead of emitting windows (each of which is each a Flux), it emits buffers (which are Collection — by default, List).

The operators for buffering mirror those for windowing: buffer, bufferTimeout, bufferUntil, bufferWhile, and bufferWhen.

Where the corresponding windowing operator opens a window, a buffering operator creates a new collection and starts adding elements to it. Where a window closes, the buffering operator emits the collection.

Buffering can also lead to dropping source elements or having overlapping buffers, as the following example shows:

```
StepVerifier.create(
    Flux.range(1, 10)
        .buffer(5, 3) //overlapping buffers
    )
        .expectNext(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
        .expectNext(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
        .expectNext(Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9, 10))
        .expectNext(Collections.singletonList(10))
        .verifyComplete();
```

Unlike in windowing, bufferUntil and bufferWhile do not emit an empty buffer, as the following example shows:

```
StepVerifier.create(
    Flux.just(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 11, 12, 13)
        .bufferWhile(i -> i % 2 == 0)
    )
    .expectNext(Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6)) // triggered by 11
    .expectNext(Collections.singletonList(12)) // triggered by 13
    .verifyComplete();
```

https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/docs/asciidoc/advancedFeatures.adoc

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have edited the question to be more specific. I don't think buffer() is going to correct the issue. The real issue is the static method Flux.fromIterable() is not working with HttpClient. In the simple example I added which is not using HttpClient, Flux.fromIterable() is working fine when a loaded queue is passed to the method. I assume something is not configured correctly, since Flux.fromIterable() is not working with HttpClient. Can you help me correct my setup?

Comment: @ChrisGrimes sorry I cant answer why it doesnt work.   Looking at the official documentation, looks like they use  
HttpClient.create()
           .post()
           .uri("http://example.com")
           .send(Flux.just(bb1, bb2, bb3))
           .responseSingle((res, content) -> Mono.just(res.status().code()))
           .block();
 
 
 HttpClient.create()
           .baseUri("http://example.com")
           .post()
           .send(ByteBufFlux.fromString(flux))
           .responseSingle((res, content) -> Mono.just(res.status().code()))
           .block();

Comment: @ChrisGrimeshttps://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/0.8.4.RELEASE/api/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.html   They use Flux.just and Flux.fromString